# Android - Wake lock not acquiring properly, app needs to keep running in standby

Tags: android, accelerometer, standby, wakelock, android-wake-lock

In my app, in the onCreate() method of the main activity I am creating a wake lock so that the CPU will keep running if the phone goes on standb/screen turns off.

Also in the onCreate method I have an intent to create a service that uses the accelerometer. This service needs to be continuously running while the app is open and monitoring accelerometer values (I know this isn't good for battery but I need it to do that). Here is my code at the moment and the service starts fine.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Howaya");
        wl.acquire();

        if (appStart == true)  
        { 
            Intent AccelService = new Intent(this, Accelerometer.class);
            AccelService.putExtra("unreg", false);
            startService(AccelService);
        }
        appStart = false;
  }
```

I have the following permission set in my manifest -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

I have tried this with different locks - dim screen and full brightness to no avail too. My output on logcat is here -

```
F/PowerManager(15628): android.util.Log$TerribleFailure: WakeLock finalized while still held: Howaya
F/PowerManager(15628):  at android.util.Log.wtf(Log.java:260)
F/PowerManager(15628):  at android.util.Log.wtf(Log.java:239)
F/PowerManager(15628):  at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.finalize(PowerManager.java:329)
F/PowerManager(15628):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

I have seen people saying that partial wakelocks don't work like they should do, such as this link [Google standby error page](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3708) but this was released and closed last year so I don't know is that the case, can anyone help here please? I have a HTC Desire as regards that last point too, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In my app, in the onCreate() method of the main activity I am creating a wake lock so that the CPU will keep running if the phone goes on standb/screen turns off.

Please use `android:keepScreenOn` on one of the widgets in your layout instead. That is far, far safer for activities than manually dealing with a `WakeLock`. Plus, you don't need the `WAKE_LOCK` permission then, IIRC.

> My output on logcat is here

That error is because you never release the `WakeLock`. Please do not leak `WakeLocks`.

Now, you managed to write all of this prose and include all of these listings, and you forgot one little thing: **actually telling us what your question is**. This is a rather important item for a question-and-answer site like StackOverflow. And, no, "can anyone help here please?" does not count as a question when you never define what "help" it is you are looking to receive.

Comment: Ok sorry if I was unclear and thank you for the reply. My question was how can I get a wakelock running on my phone so that my app runs while the screen is still off, as the code I am using above isn't working. I would prefer not to have the screen on so that it won't waste as much battery and not have to use the widget in case I decided to put it on the market (then other users would have to use the widget)

Comment: @bobby123: An activity cannot have a logical need for a partial `WakeLock`. A *service* might have a need for a partial `WakeLock`, but not an activity, whose only purpose for existing is to display stuff on the screen. So, either get your `WakeLock` out of the activity and into the service (adjusting your business logic to match), or use `android:keepScreenOn`. Acquire your `WakeLock` in `onCreate()` of your service and release it in `onDestroy()`. Use `startForeground()` so your service isn't nuked and give the user an easy way to get to an activity to stop the service.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know, thanks. I'll move the wake lock to the service as that's what I really need it for. I have a menu button for the user to end the service at any time. One last question please, do you know should the method onSensorChanged() for the accelerometer still work while under a partial wake lock or is this still an issue with Google?

Comment: @bobby123: "do you know should the method onSensorChanged() for the accelerometer still work while under a partial wake lock or is this still an issue with Google" -- I am unaware that sensor behavior under `WakeLocks` is documented, which means it may vary by device. However, I haven't paid a lot of attention to this particular issue, since it's not in my area of interest, so I am far from expert on that topic, sorry.

Comment: From everything I've read I think it may be device specific alright, thought I'd ask anyways. Ok I'll your advice and thanks again.

Answer (score 10):

Problem occurs because your WakeLock object is a local scoped variable inside OnCreate method. After method being executed - WakeLock object is no more referenced - thus eligible for garbage collection. If Dalvik GC occurs - object is ready for finalize - and finalizer internal code warns You, that WakeLock is still held - and active - but will be GC'ed. You have to obtain new WakeLock object and assign it to a field of class type WakeLock in Your activity derived class. Read about Object Oriented programming and Garbage Collector - You will understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As @Michal P said, you acquire a wakelock in onCreate method, but you never release it.

When GC scan this zero referenced object, call default finalize method, but actually it is active.

```
  @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        synchronized (mToken) {
            if (mHeld) {
                Log.wtf(TAG, "WakeLock finalized while still held: " + mTag);
                Trace.asyncTraceEnd(Trace.TRACE_TAG_POWER, mTraceName, 0);
                try {
                    mService.releaseWakeLock(mToken, 0);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```